# WordPress Pulldown Menu Color Change CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, dom

Is it possible to target only the "Pulldown Parent Menu" link below in CSS (I can't modify the code below)?

The line of code I wish to target so that I can modify it in CSS is:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=8">Pulldown Menu Parent</a>
```

The page-item-8 class is dynamically generated so I can't rely on it.

The full code is:

```
<div id="access" role="navigation">

<div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a></div>

<div class="menu">
<ul>

<li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>

<li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=19">Contact</a></li>

<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=8">Pulldown Menu Parent</a>

<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=9">Test Page 2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=11">Test Page 3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=13">Test Page 4</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=15">Test Page 5</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=17">Test Page 6</a></li>
</ul>

</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div><!-- #access -->
```

How can I access the Pulldown Menu Parent link above in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

At your Appearance > Menus, you can click `Screen Options` and click `CSS Classes` to add specific class for a specific menu item.

[Click here for full image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umqfo.png)